# Kotlin null check with !! does not short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: kotlin

Is Kotlin null safety check is not short circuit in if statement evaluation?
Please see following example.

```
fun main(){
    var myEmps : List<Emp>? = null
    println(myEmps) //null
    var address = if(myEmps?.get(0)!!.address?.line1!=null) myEmps?.get(0)!!.address!!.line1 else "no address" //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    println(address)
}

data class Emp (var name: String?, var address: Address?) {}
data class Address(var line1: String?, var line2: String) {}
```

My assumption is since *myEmps* is null and *null safety check* is there, the *get(0)!!* should not be evaluated at all and control should jump to *else* block. but the behavior is otherwise and I am seeing a *NullPointerException*.

And the same with address element, as below.

```
var address = if(myEmps?.get(0)?.address!!.line1!=null) myEmps?.get(0)?.address!!.line1 else "no address" //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So null check *with !!* comes with this caveat of short-circuit not applicable and always ensure entire chain is properly checked? If so, how good is this useful in such scenarios of object chain validations?

Comment: What do you think `!!` does? Because its goal is literally to throw a `NullPointerException` when it encounters `null`.

Comment: @A Again, point here is there is a null safety (?) evaluation prior to that if you notice. Since my object is null and that check would fail in the first place, why does the next part is coming into evaluation at all? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you understand how null-safe property access works. It simply defers the `null` further down the chain. If any part of the null-safe chain is `null`, the whole thing will be `null`, and adding a `!!` after it will throw a `NullPointerException` because it's `null`.

Comment: Why do you think `get()` should not get evaluated? `obj?.call()` returns null in both case if prior `obj` is null as well as when `call` returns null, basically null propagation to next statement.

Comment: Probably you meant to do: `myEmps?.get(0)?.let { if (it.address.line1 != null) ... }` where you ignore things if either of `myEmps` is `null` or `get` returns `null`.

Comment: And regarding if you want the statement to jump to else block, you can simply propagate the null forward till the last statement: `if(myEmps?.get(0)?.address?.line1 != null)`

Comment: So following are not equivalent?

`println(if(myEmps?.get(0)?.address!!.line1!=null) myEmps?.get(0)?.address!!.line1 else "no address")`

and 

`if(myEmps!=null && myEmps.get(0) !=null && myEmps.get(0).address!=null) {
        var address : Address? = myEmps.get(0).address
        if (address!=null) {
            if (address.line1 != null)
              println("address1")
            else
              println("no address")
        } else
           println("no address")        
    } else
      println("no address")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of a chain of calls as a series of steps that evaluate to something. Each call on the chain is called on the previous evaluated value. Any `?.` call will evaluate to a nullable type.

First you have `myEmps` which is a `List<Emp>?`.

Then you call `?.get(0)`. This evaluates to an `Emp?` because of the null-safe `?.` call.

Then you call `!!` on the `Emp?`. `!!` means to evaluate it to either a non-nullable `Emp` or throw a KotlinNullPointerException. It is essentially the opposite of a null-safe call.

What you actually need if you want null-safety is to continue using null-safe `?.` calls all the way down the chain once you have something that is nullable, so you should replace `!!` with `?`. Like this:

```
var address = if(myEmps?.get(0)?.address?.line1 != null) myEmps?.get(0)?.address!!.line1 else "no address"
```

The second use of `!!` is OK to keep since it happens after your `!= null` check so you know the `Emp?` is not going to evaluate to `null`. But it is clumsy to repeat that long call chain. You can eliminate this if-statement by using the Elvis operator `?:` like this:

```
var address = myEmps?.get(0)?.address?.line1 ?: "no address"
```

Comment: That clarifies, Thank much!